# Redimensionar Imagenes CSS react

Tags: html, css, reactjs, imagen

Estoy aprendiendo css y estaba intentado que estás 3 imágenes fueran del mismo tamaño en el ancho, ya que en el alto si que son de la misma medida.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
.imagen-testimonio{
    height: 100%;
    width: auto;
}
```

He visto que para estos casos se suele usar **max-heigth: 100%;** y **max-width100%;** pero aún así me salen de diferente tamaño.

Gracias.

Comment: Si quieres que las imágenes sean del mismo ancho usa la propiedad `width`, por ejemplo `width: 300px`, pero si en origen no son del mismo ancho, al ponerle el ancho fijo o varía el alto o se verán muy mal

Comment: Lo he probado con width: 200px y ahí todas las imágenes son del mismo ancho pero la primera de por sí es más ancha que es resto, por lo que se ve un poco mal con respecto al resto, me gustaría saber si existe alguna manera hacerlo sin que pierda calidad.